# Resharper with QUnit - Reference Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, resharper, qunit

When I am running QUnit tests with Resharper, they are failing with a message which indicates jquery-ui has not been loaded.

When I inspect the HTML for Resharper's test page, I see that it has loaded jquery twice, once before jquery-ui, and once after.

I have removed all "reference path" lines from my test javascript file, but it seems that Resharper is somehow caching these references.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem (i.e. refreshed the references) by right clicking on Solution Explorer and selecting "Run Tests", as opposed to rerunning tests from the 'Unit Test Sessions' window. The resharper plugin seems slightly buggy. Other issues I have had have been resolved by restarting Visual Studio.